# What is the dollar caret zero variable ( $^0 ) in Perl?

Tags: perl, special-variables

I've found some Perl code that makes the following check:

[image: As displayed on the screen]

```perl
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32')
```

What is the `$^0` variable? It looks like it contains the architecture/OS of the machine it's running on, but I don't know if that's the result of assigning it elsewhere in the script (maybe it's the result of a regex match, though I can't see any match operations performed before that point), or whether that variable always has a value related to the machine it's running on.

I'd like to check the OS and bitness of the machine running the script, and would like to know if I can use $^0 to help me with that (if not, then I'm still curious what it is).

I'd rather not publish other parts of the Perl script, as it's proprietary.

This strikes me as the sort of question that should have been asked before, but Google isn't much use, thanks to the special characters (I often think the inability to Google Perl code led in part to its demise), and Stack Overflow doesn't have any useful suggested questions either.

There's no match for $^0 or $^1 or $^# on the [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) page, and I'm not convinced that $^N or $^X are related.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: @Mat: A link on its own is not a useful comment. Please see information of what I've already searched for on that page. If there's something I've missed, please indicate where it is, and copy the relevant part for reference.

Comment: It's `$^O` not `$^0`

Comment: I've used $^O  to determine the operating system before to check if the script is being run on Windows (=~ /win/i), Linux or FreeBSD (=~ /linux|freebsd/i) but I don't have more details or a full list of operating system strings to supply you with what I feel would be a properly useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a zero.

It is the letter "O", capitalized.

In [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), search for `OSNAME`, which is the long form name of the variable when you use [English](https://perldoc.perl.org/English.html):

> The name of the operating system under which this copy of Perl was
>   built, as determined during the configuration process.

There is no special "dollar caret zero" variable.